# Excel Power Pivot / Data Model - passing a parameter from worksheet

Tags: excel, powerpivot, datamodel

I have a SQL query I am using for a workbook requiring multiple pivot views from the same dataset.  Part of the query is looking at a declared value and based on that value it will either return one result or another, that declared value however needs to be a parameter that end users will input into the workbook.

Normally I would use the excel function to pull the data from the SQL server and then pass a parameter in the advanced query option using " Let Parameters = Excel.CurrentWorkbook()".. however the result set it too large and therefore I need to use Power Pivot.

I however for the life of me can find no help on how to pass a parameter from a cell in a worksheet to power pivot - is this possible, is there a VB script I can use to update the query, alternatively what other options are available other than having to get the end users to go into power pivot and edit the query in the properties each time?

As the variable is used in a computation, I am not using the parameter to filter the dataset and that seems to be the only advice I have been able to find.  I am new to Power Pivot.

Answer (score 0):

I came right by doing the following:

Add the SQL query in Power Query, as a data connection only.  In the advanced query options, I added the required parameters.

I then selected the query and selected the option to load to Data Model.

Seems to be working.